# Add to cart event not passing values to google analytics dashboard

Tags: addtocart, magento2.4.5, pwa, google-analytics, venia

As We are using Magento PWA Venia setup, we integrated google analytics code to our website manually. After adding the below code , Once we click on ADD TO CART, **add_to_cart** event is firing in **Google analytics dashboard**.

src/talons/ProductFullDetail/useProductFullDetail.js  : https://pastebin.com/s0hVXuvR

```
GTMEventTrigger({
                 route: window.location.pathname,
                 event: 'add_to_cart',
                 title: document.title
                });
```

Analytics Dashboard :

[image]

**Issue** :

The added item's values like **sku, product_price**, are not firing in dashboard. So i tried below code, but still values are not passing. Am i using right code to pass the values ? Is there any way to debug ?

```
GTMEventTrigger({
      route: window.location.pathname,
      event: gtag("event", "add_to_cart", {
        items: [
          {
            'prid': product.id,           
            'price': product?.price_range?.maximum_price?.final_price.value,
          }
        ]
      }),
      title: document.title
    });
```

Comment: in wich file you have add this script?

Comment: @RohitGohel previous developers wrote the code in this file :  src/talons/ProductFullDetail - useProductFullDetail.js

Comment: https://pastebin.com/1uHEFNbH here is full code

Comment: if you search for `GTMEventTrigger`, you ll get the code

Comment: @RohitGohel i guess they are using this code : `event: 'add_to_cart',` to pass the add to cart parameter to analytics, but as they are not passing the values to it, may be that is the reason values are not displaying in google analytics

Comment: yes into this window.location.pathname line pathname is not defined anywhere in the file so first need to check in that

Comment: @RohitGohel thanks , i searched `window.location.pathname` in other files, that is present in other files :  https://prnt.sc/7SJssKC4XBl0

Comment: yes search pathname variable into other file and check which value are pass into this variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152174/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-rohit-gohel).